# Understanding the Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree

```
struct node {
    int key;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right; 
};

struct node * newBST(int key){
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> key = key; 
    temp -> left = temp -> right = NULL; 
    return key; 
}
```

So I am unable to understand why we malloc the size of node? to struct *temp ? 
Is it so we can access the elements created in the node ?

Comment: you should `return temp;`.

Comment: What other size are you expecting to be allocated and why? You need the allocated size in the size of a structure to map a structure definition on the allocated space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reserve the memory. After `struct node {...}`, you basically now have a blueprint on how nodes are supposed to look like. Then you go to the <strike>urban</strike> memory planning office, and tell them "I'm making a new node, can I reserve 24 <strike>square meters</strike> bytes somewhere?" And they tell you "Sure, this here should be a good place, we promise not to give it to anyone else. Just make sure not to mess with anything outside those 24 <strike>square meters</strike> bytes, or bad things will happen". So you take your `temp` address, go there and start laying out stuff: `key` goes in *these* 8 <strike>square meters</strike> bytes, and let's clean *these* 8 and these *other* 8 from all the cruft that may have been there before...

---

*) `int` nowadays usually takes up 8 bytes of memory, and each pointer does as well. But this is dependent on your computer and compiler.